# iOS MDM Features

Tags: ios, mdm

We are going to deploy our apps to several devices. There are some problems we want to solve.
1. Installing configuration profile to iPad. (Disable homebutton)
2. Update our apps automatically

So far we found some solutions but not perfect, which are
1. Get configuration profile from server and open it in safari, then the safari will open and install the profile in settings. But this solution causes so many steps and bad customer experience.
2. We found that the new iOS 7 will support automatically update in app store.

Meanwhile, I found MDM may be a solution for my problem. 
Here are some questions about MDM.
1. Can we install configuration profile automatically with MDM, instead of using safari and settings?
2. Can we update apps in customers' devices automatically without using app store?
3. There are some features in MDM, does it mean we can access data and control customers devices without notice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we install configuration profile automatically with MDM, instead of using safari and settings?

Yes. You can. It will be invisible to a user (except, if a configuration profile requires some user interaction).

> Can we update apps in customers' devices automatically without using app store?

For non supervised devices, you can install/upgrade an application, but a user will be required to accept it.

For supervised devices you can install/upgrade apps silently (starting from iOS 7).

> There are some features in MDM, does it mean we can access data and control customers devices without notice?

Generally no. MDM doesn't give you an access to customers data, except a case if application is specifically designed to return data through MDM.

Comment: Tanks for answering. Can we use MDM in Appcelerator Titanium (cross-platform)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "use MDM". If you are talking about installation of configuration profiles, in such case the answer is "MDM is server side only code. MDM client side is integrated into system". If you are asking whether you can access data of Titanium app - I don't know, but most likely yes.